# Switching unique identifiers with entityframework

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I am trying to switch Unique identifiers between 2 entities. My current solution works but is far from pretty. First i set one username to "temp" so there is no overlap in usernames. Afterwards I switch them.

```
public void SwitchUsernames(Guid personIdOld, Guid personIdNew)
{
    // Get accounts
    var personOld = GetAccount(personIdOld);
    var personNew = GetAccount(personIdNew);

    // switch usernames
    string usernamePersonOld = personOld.username;
    string usernamePersonNew = personNew.username;
    try
    {
        personOld.SetUsername("Temp");
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception) { throw; }
    try
    {
        personNew.SetUsername(usernamePersonOld);
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception) 
    {
        personOld.SetUsername(usernamePersonOld);
        Context.SaveChanges();
        throw; 
    }
    try
    {
        personOld.SetUsername(usernamePersonNew);
        Context.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (Exception) 
    {
        personOld.SetUsername(usernamePersonOld);
        Context.SaveChanges();
        personNew.DomainAccounts.SetUsername(usernamePersonNew);
        Context.SaveChanges();
        throw; 
    }
}
```

The trycatch blocks are there to rollback everything in case something fails. If i do not save the context after every change it will fail. I really would like this a lot cleaner but i dont know if there is a way. I am here to learn so please enlighten me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I really would like this a lot cleaner

Use a transaction, when an error occurs it will not push to the database so no need for a rollback.

Something like this:

```
        public void SwitchUsernames(Guid personIdOld, Guid personIdNew)
        {
            // Get accounts
            var personOld = Accounts.Find(personIdOld);
            var personNew = Accounts.Find(personIdNew);

            // switch usernames
            string usernamePersonOld = personOld.UserName;
            string usernamePersonNew = personNew.UserName;

            using (var tran = _context.Database.BeginTransaction())
            {
                var temp = "TempName" + Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
                personOld.UserName = temp;
                _context.SaveChanges();

                personNew.UserName = usernamePersonOld;
                _context.SaveChanges();

                personOld.UserName = usernamePersonNew;
                _context.SaveChanges();

                tran.Commit();
            }
        }
```

Comment: It took me some time to understand the enhancement but if i am correct its all about the transactions with the database. I am going to try it out soon. Looks a lot better! No need to rollback thru try and catch

Comment: This is the accepted answer. The code is alot cleaner without the three try catch statements. Because it is in a transaction it will not commit if there will be an exception. Still "anoying" i have to save after every change but i can live with that:) Thanks a lot!